# Is the equality $H^{\otimes 2} \mathsf{CNOT} H^{\otimes 2} |xy\rangle = \mathsf{CNOT} |yx\rangle$ correct?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-computer

Is the following equality correct?

$$H^{\otimes 2} \, \mathsf{CNOT} \, H^{\otimes 2} |xy\rangle = \mathsf{CNOT} |yx\rangle$$

The [solution](http://ml693.user.srcf.net/solutions.pdf) says `yes`. It claims that the LHS maps $|10\rangle$ to $|10\rangle$. But isn't it the case that $\mathsf{CNOT} |11\rangle$ rather than $\mathsf{CNOT} |01\rangle$ equals $|10\rangle$? If yes, then why is this equality correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, and your solutions are wrong. Acting on the basis ket $|10 \rangle$, the right-hand side maps to
\begin{align}
\mathsf{CNOT} \ \mathsf{SWAP}|10\rangle
& = 
\mathsf{CNOT}|01\rangle
\\ & = |01\rangle.
\end{align}
Their assertion for the left-hand side is correct, though:
\begin{align}
H^{\otimes 2} \, \mathsf{CNOT} \, H^{\otimes 2}|10\rangle
& = 
H^{\otimes 2} \, \mathsf{CNOT} \frac{|0\rangle-|1\rangle}{\sqrt{2}}|+\rangle
\\& = 
H^{\otimes 2}  \frac{|0\rangle|+\rangle-|1\rangle\,X|+\rangle}{\sqrt{2}}
\\& = 
H^{\otimes 2}  \frac{|0\rangle|+\rangle-|1\rangle|+\rangle}{\sqrt{2}}
\\& = 
H^{\otimes 2}  \frac{|0\rangle-|1\rangle}{\sqrt{2}}|+\rangle
\\ & = |10\rangle.
\end{align}
As such, under the standard conventions, the equality is false.

On the other hand, it *is* true that 
$$
H^{\otimes 2} \, \mathsf{CNOT} \, H^{\otimes 2}
=
\mathsf{SWAP} \ \mathsf{CNOT} \ \mathsf{SWAP}.
$$
Either way, you should check with your instructor (or, if self-studying, find a better problem set).